# Unauthorized user when calling Laravel 5.3 API with Auth0 from curl

Tags: curl, laravel-5, auth0

Looking for the convenience of Auth0 to sort out JWTs between my Angular 2 client and Laravel 5.3 API. I've followed (and double-checked that I've followed) Auth0's getting started guide:

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/php-laravel

But can't seem to get it to authenticate me. When I curl as follows:

```
curl --request GET --url http://localhost/api/test --header 'authorization: auth0_id_token'
```

I get:

```
Unauthorized user curl: (6) Could not resolve host: auth0_id_token
```

In my `\routes\api`, I have:

```
Route::get('/test', array('middleware' => 'auth0.jwt', function() {
    return "Hello " . Auth0::jwtuser()->name;
}));
```

I'm generating the `id_token` using this:

https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#!#post--oauth-ro

and can see when I go to (https://manage.auth0.com/#/users) that Auth0 thinks the user has logged in.

Any pointers for where I should be looking to try and debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to include a bearer token in the HTTP `Authorization` header is to use the `Bearer` authentication scheme, so your header should be:

```
Authorization: Bearer [auth0_id_token]
```

Additionally, the error you received from `curl` also indicates that the command is not being parsed as you intended, more specifically, it seems `'authorization: auth0_id_token'` is being parsed as multiple arguments which results in the `auth0_id_token` part being considered as an URL which will fail when trying to resolve the host; try to use double quotes instead.

Comment: Thanks so much @João Angelo. That was exactly the problem and, although I'd checked I had all the Laravel bits right, I hadn't spotted that my Curl was wrong. In case it helps anyone else, the working command is: curl --request GET --url localhost/api/test --header "Authorization: Bearer auth0_id_token". Thanks again.